# Is an IEnumerable able to contain multiple class types?

Tags: c#, containers

I am currently in a situation in which I would like to fill an `IEnumerable`, with different types of viewmodels/class.

I am making a container element in Sitecore, and all the items inside the container is supposed to be parsed into the the same `IEnumerable`..

Each item has its own view model => so parsing the actual Item to a C# class should not be a problem => its just the order, and being able to parse it all into one `IEnumerable` that seems tricky => is it possible?

Any suggestions on whether this is possible and if so how?

Comment: Please provide sample code.

Comment: I don't know anything about Sitecore, but if you could let them use the same interface (maybe, say, IViewModel), then you could just make a list of IViewModel objects. You could also consider creating a wrapper object that holds all the viewmodel information.

Comment: If your searching to add IEnumerable<Different> and iterate i think it doesn't work directly. Either you need a base class or use Tuple or ArrayList for the same . https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_arraylist.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `IEnumerable<object>` and then check the type of your object when you will iterate, will that be enough for you?

Comment: Would I in razor be able to determine the type of the object?

Comment: @anita In any given situation, if you're to use IEnumerable<object>, to determine the type of object underneath, you're going to have to use metaprogramming in order to get the actual type.

Answer (score 1):

From what I could get out of your question, I think you need to utilize the `Inheritance` and `Polymorphism` concepts of `OOP`.
A sample code:

```
interface ICanMilk
{
    int GetAmountOfMilk();
}
class Cow : ICanMilk
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int GetAmountOfMilk()
    {
        return 1000;
    }
}
class Sheep : ICanMilk
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int GetAmountOfMilk()
    {
        return 500;
    }
}
class Goat : ICanMilk
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int GetAmountOfMilk()
    {
        return 100;
    }
}
class Program
{

    public static void Main(string [] args)
    {
        List<ICanMilk> list = new List<ICanMilk>();
        list.Add(new Cow());
        list.Add(new Goat());
        list.Add(new Sheep());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An IEnumerable can only contain instances of a single type. However, that type can be an Interface. So if your models all implement the same Interface, you can stuff them all into the same IEnumerable.